# Why didn't Ryuk drop his own death note?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note

In [Death Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Death_Note_episodes), Why did Ryuk use Sidoh's death-note rather than his own for dropping into human world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So he won't be obliged to follow the human until death that will get the ownership of the death note. He just followed Light out of boredom and he is interesting.